How to disable keyboard suggestions in WebView using Java
I'm working on an Android app that uses a WebView to display a custom editor. I need to disable the keyboard suggestions strip and switch to an alphanumeric keyboard, similar to the behavior of an EditText's inputType "textVisiblePassword" in XML. I've tried the following approaches without success:

Setting spellcheck, autocomplete, and autocorrect attributes to false via JavaScript.
Using a JavaScript interface to control the keyboard behavior when Boolean is focused.

Here's my current code:
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
            boolean focused = jsonObject.getBoolean("focused");
            if (focused) {

                // Set the input type to visible password
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(webView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                webView.postDelayed(() -> {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("document.activeElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');", null);
                }, 100);
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, "Android");

Despite these efforts, the keyboad suggestions strip still appears, and the keyboard doesn’t switch to alphanumeric mode.
My aim is to employ the textVisiblePassword feature that we normally have in Android XML EditText to WebView when text fields like contenteditables are focused.
